# Count records based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simple table. This data is for January 2023.

[image]

I want to count the number of "A" which is on Monday.

I tried

`=COUNTIFS(C3:AG3,"A",$C$2:$AG$2,WEEKDAY($C$2:$AG$2)=2)`

But I am not getting the correct result

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are those actually dates in row 2? If so, I suggest you add a formula above them to return the weekday for each date, and refer to that in your COUNTIFS formula.

Comment: No they are just numbers. Do you think that is the problem? Should I use combination of WEEKDAY(DATE()). I do not want to use a helper row/column.

Comment: Something like `=COUNTIFS(C5:AG5,"A",$C$2:$AG$2,WEEKDAY(DATE(2023,1,$C$2:$AG$2))=2)` I can see the array as TRUE and FALSE but it is not returning the result.

Comment: You must convert them to actual dates. Otherwise they will be treated as days in Jan 1900.

Comment: Dhruva, check my comment below Harun's post. Is that what you are trying?

Comment: Yes @Rory. This is why I was trying `WEEKDAY(DATE())`

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes i think that is what i want. let me test it.

Comment: Why can't you just put actual dates in those cells? If you don't, you will have to keep adjusting any count formulas that assume a year and/or month.

Comment: yes @Rory. That does make sense. will save me from using the DATE function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `SUMPRODUCT` with DOUBLE -ve as @Harun24HR is using. The double negative will coerce the `TRUE` and `FALSE` values into **1's** and **0's**.

Since your dates are actually just numbers (*I would agree with @Rory that using Dates instead of Numbers is a better idea.*), you will have to convert them to dates and your idea of using `DATE()` and `WEEKDAYS()` is absolutely correct!

Just remember that the syntax of `WEEKDAYS()` is `WEEKDAY(serial_number,[return_type])`
Based on the `return_type`, the [WEEKDAYS()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weekday-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a) will return a different day.

The formula that you need is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(DATE(2023,1,$C$5:$AG$5))=2)*(C6:AG6="A"))
```

[image]

Even though you did not ask for this, I would like to share why using `SUMPRODUCT()` is a better option.

Let's say you want to count the **A's** which not only falls on **Mondays** but also on **Fridays**. (*I thought of this because in the company that I was working for, if the employee took unapproved leave on Friday or Monday, then the weekends were also counted.*)

In such a case, instead of using

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(DATE(2023,1,$C$5:$AG$5))=6)*(C6:AG6="A")) + SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(DATE(2023,1,$C$5:$AG$5))=2)*(C6:AG6="A"))`, you can use the `+` for `OR` condition to handle both scenarios. For example

`=SUMPRODUCT(--((WEEKDAY(DATE(2023,1,$C$5:$AG$5))=2)+(WEEKDAY(DATE(2023,1,$C$5:$AG$5))=6))*(C6:AG6="A"))`

[image]

Comment: WOW! I did not know about the `+`. Thank you for taking out time to explain everything in so much detail!!!

Comment: BTW I have decided to change the numbers to DATE as recommended by @Rory. Less typing and less headache :D

Comment: Yup that is a good decision :)

Answer (score 1):

there is no real need of using WEEKDAY because you are counting Mondays and each Monday takes places only after a Sunday with the value `W/O`. So you can do it like this:

[image]

Formula to get output is an array formula (it must be entered pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> or it won't work):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TRANSPOND(C3:AF3)&TRANSPOND(D3:AG3)="W/OA"))+IF(AND(H3&I3="W/OW/O",C3="A"),1,0)
```

The IF part is just to check if the month starts on a Monday and with the value A. We check if the first day of the month is monday by checking if days six and seven are weekends (with the value `W/O` both of them).

This is how it works:

1. `(TRANSPOND(C3:AF3)&TRANSPOND(D3:AG3)` will convert the row to column and concatenate. Notice the first TRANSPOND excludes the 31th day and the second one excludes the 1st day. This is because a Monday goes always after a Sunday, so we check all days except the first one. This create an array like this (visual example with Employee5):

[image]

2. The previous formula is wrapped inside a [Double Unary Operator](https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary) that will check of the previous array if any of the concatenated strings are equal to `W/OA`. IF true, will return 1, else 0. And because it's a SUMPRODUCT it will sum up all, bringint output 5 in this case.
3. The IF part, as said before, checks if the first day of the month is Monday with `A` value (remember we excluded first day check on step 1) so it must be donde this way. Will add 1 or 0 to previous output depending on the case. Check example `If the month starts on Monday, it works` on the first image to understand better.

Comment: Thanks for another interesting approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUMPRODUCT()`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY($C$2:$AG$2)=2)*(C3:AG3="A"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Harun. This got me the answer but will this work for any other month which has 31 days? How was the weekday calculated as the headers are just numbers...

Comment: I think it should be `=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(DATE(2023,1,$C$2:$AG$2))=2)*(C3:AG3="A"))`?

Answer (score 0):

So this is for you to consider and shows how to identify Mondays:

[image]

You can think how you can approach your data.

Comment: Thanks Solar but I think this is a slightly more complex approach...

Comment: @Dhruva so it is a simple example of weekday() which all the others are using - I suggested it to you so you might try implementing it yourself - often better than just copying another’s solution.